# Handle multiple values in column

Tags: python, r, database

Consider an example from data.table package in R:

```
DT = data.table(ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"), a = 1:6, b = 7:12, c=13:18)
DT = DT[, .(A=list(a), B=list(b), C=list(c)), by=ID]
DT
   ID     A     B        C
1:  b 1,2,3 7,8,9 13,14,15
2:  a   4,5 10,11    16,17
3:  c     6    12       18
```

After this I want to write this to file in order to share this structure. However, it prohibits writing such things with write.csv because of *list* type. The solution I found is to convert those columns to *string*. However, how can I read this from file? Is there some unified format that can be read in (almost) any language without much effort?

Comment: Have you considered JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a tab-seperated file as follows:

```
DT2 <- DT[, .(A=toString(a), B=toString(b), C=toString(c)), by=ID]
write.table(DT2, "dt2.txt", sep="\t", row.names = FALSE)
```

which should be readable by most languages.

---

When you want to preserve the lists, transforming to JSON as suggested by @TigerhawkT3 would be the best option:

```
DT3 <- DT[, .(A=list(a), B=list(b), C=list(c)), by=ID]
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(DT3)
```

which gives:

```
[{"ID":"b","A":[1,2,3],"B":[7,8,9],"C":[13,14,15]},{"ID":"a","A":[4,5],"B":[10,11],"C":[16,17]},{"ID":"c","A":[6],"B":[12],"C":[18]}]
```

Comment: @nmerci added an option how to get a JSON as well

Comment: Why the `complex="list"` argument?

Comment: @nicola though it was necessary to retain the list formatting, but apperently not (after trying it without the `complex="list"` argument); removed it now

Comment: Yeah, it seems that `list`s are correctly handled by default and `complex` refers to complex numbers. +1 of course.